# Localhost POST request for GroupMe Bot

Tags: node.js, curl, bots, groupme

I'm trying to test a GroupMe bot that I made using Node.js. I'm using the [Example Bot](https://github.com/groupme/bot-tutorial-nodejs) by GroupMe. After running   `foreman start` and 
`curl -X POST -d \cool guy\ localhost:5000` (from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518115/testing-post-request-with-groupme-bot)), I get the error `curl: (1) Protocol "guy http" not supported or disabled in libcurl`. I tried wrapping the message in double quotes, but that only resulted in a syntax error. How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

I tried

```
$ curl -X POST -d "cool guy" localhost:5000
```

and got the following error from foreman:

```
22:04:16 web.1  | started with pid 5788
22:04:32 web.1  | undefined:1
22:04:32 web.1  | cool guy
22:04:32 web.1  | ^
22:04:32 web.1  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token c
22:04:32 web.1  |     at Object.parse (native)
22:04:32 web.1  |     at Object.respond (C:\Users\Nicky\Documents\GitHub\groupme-jarvis\bot.js:11:24)
22:04:32 web.1  |     at apply (C:\Users\Nicky\Documents\GitHub\groupme-jarvis\node_modules\director\lib\director\router.js:448:19)
22:04:32 web.1  |     at _every (C:\Users\Nicky\Documents\GitHub\groupme-jarvis\node_modules\director\lib\director\router.js:30:9)
22:04:32 web.1  |     at Router.invoke (C:\Users\Nicky\Documents\GitHub\groupme-jarvis\node_modules\director\lib\director\router.js:454:5)
22:04:32 web.1  |     at IncomingMessage.parseAndInvoke (C:\Users\Nicky\Documents\GitHub\groupme-jarvis\node_modules\director\lib\director\http\index.js:175:10)
22:04:32 web.1  |     at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:199:16)
22:04:32 web.1  |     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
22:04:32 web.1  |     at _stream_readable.js:908:16
22:04:32 web.1  |     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
22:04:32 web.1  | exited with code 1
22:04:32 system | sending SIGKILL to all processes
```

Comment: maybe `curl ... -d "cool guy" loc...` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shelter that didn't work sorry. see the edit above

Comment: (not a curl expert, just reading the man page), maybe `--data-binary` or `--data-url*` instead of `-d` would be more appropriate? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add http:// in front of localhost. Libcurl, the library that curl uses,  supports many different protocols. Curl is correctly assuming http, but seems to be have a bug.

Edit: after reading the question again, I see that curl was compiled without http support. If you compiled it yourself, make sure to enable http support. If you installed it using a distributions package manager, try reinstalling.